# Cannot Run Macro SOLVER.XLAM!Main. The macro may not be available

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I wrote a macro that consolidates two files into one new file on excel 2007. I sent it to someone who tried to run it on his excel 2010 and he received the error in the Title of this question. We have tried to

- make sure he had the Solver addin activated and a reference to it checked
- pasted this in the immediate window `application.run "solver.xlam!auto_open"`
- I tried to disable the Solver addin on my end, save and resend to him
- make sure macros were enabled

The solver addin isn't even necessary for this program, as far as I can tell. I should mention that the macro works great on my excel 2007.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The strangest thing happened. When the workbook got emailed the button the macro was originally assigned to got changed to solver.xlam. All I had to do was instruct him to reassign the button to my macro. How odd is that?! Curious if anyone else has experienced anything like that.